# How to find duplicate columns which are having same values in more than one columns(column names are given)

Tags: mysql

I am using **mysql db** and created a table as.

```
 student_id roll_no student_name    date_of_join    email_id
    1   ERD001  Ankit   2013-10-16  ankit@abc.in
    2   ERD002  Aman    2013-10-16  aman@abc.in
    3   ERD003  Alok    2013-10-16  alok@abc.in
    4   ERD004  Anshuman    2013-10-16  anshu@abc.in
    6   ERD002  Anil    2013-10-16  anil@abc.in 
    7   ERD004  Hemant  2013-10-17  hemant@abc.in
```

Here I want to select all records which are having same roll number and date of join.
     i.e. i want to fetch records-

```
  2             ERD002      Aman            2013-10-16  aman@abc.in
    6           ERD002      Anil                2013-10-16  anil@abc.in
```

because both records having same (ERD002,2013-10-16 ).

I have tried as.

```
SELECT * FROM students
GROUP BY roll_no,date_of_join
HAVING COUNT(student_id)>1
```

But It gives single record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a query that should work:

```
SELECT * FROM students s
INNER JOIN
(SELECT roll_no, date_of_join FROM students
GROUP BY roll_no, date_of_join
HAVING COUNT(student_id)>1) rd on s.roll_no = rd.roll_no and s.date_of_join = rd.date_of_join
ORDER BY s.roll_no, s.date_of_join
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use `exists` :

```
select * 
from students t 
where exists 
(
  select 1 
  from students
  where roll_no = t.roll_no and 
        date_of_join = t.date_of_join and 
        student_id <> t.student_id
)
```

Comment: Thanks Grisha for your response. It also works and gives same result